# Setting property of plugin dynamically based on browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently implementing a [accordion image slider](http://www.jqueryscript.net/accordion/jQuery-Plugin-for-Responsive-Accordion-Generator-awsAccordion.html) into a project and the slider has the following optional settings.

```
$("#accordion").awsAccordion({
    type: "horizontal",
    cssAttrsHor: {
        ulWidth: "responsive",
        liHeight: 500,
        liWidth: 50
    },
    cssAttrsVer: {
        ulWidth: "responsive"
    },
    startSlide: 2,
    openCloseHelper: {
        openIcon: "plus",
        closeIcon: "minus"
    },
    openOnebyOne: true,
    classTab: "small",
    slideOn: "click",
    autoPlay: true,
    autoPlaySpeed: 3000
})
```

Where it says: type:"horizontal",
I want to change this to: type:"vertical",
When the browser width is under 768px, is that even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by setting the `type` property by using a variable

```
var type = 'horizontal'; // Default type
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    type = 'vertical'; // When window width is less than 768, make type vertical
}

$("#accordion").awsAccordion({
    type: type, // Use variable here
    ...
});
```

---

To run the code on window resize, `resize` event can be used.

```
function update() {
    var type = 'horizontal'; // Default type
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        type = 'vertical'; // When window width is less than 768, make type vertical
    }

    $("#accordion").awsAccordion({
        type: type, // Use variable here
        ...
    });
}

$(window).resize(update).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Thanks that works, I did have an example I worked on but you would have laughed! just while I have your attention can it be set so it changes back to the previous type when the browser goes back to wider than 768, again thanks for the help. i'm guessing an else statement

Comment: @webmonkey237 just put another conditional in an "on resize" method: $(window).on('resize', function(){ ... });

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added and again works great, looks like it needs a refresh to reload the script correctly while its functioning/sliding as it goes all crazy when the browser window gets adjusted, I should be able to use what you have supplied. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

try to make it variable

```
$(function(){
var x;
if(window.width<786){
x = "vertical";}else{
x= "horizontal";}
});
```

and then you put your code here as defined below

```
$("#accordion").awsAccordion({
  type: x , 
  cssAttrsHor:{
      ulWidth:"responsive",
      liHeight:500,
      liWidth:50
  },
```

Comment: if you enclose in "" it becomes a string not a variable